# mysql dll's never show up in bin folder

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, dll

My website uses MySql as its db. I added references to the MySql.Data,MySql.Data.Entity,MySql.Web dll's using add reference and browsing to their location. However, those dll's are never in my bin folder and therefore don't get published with the site when I publish to the host server. If I go to add them again, they are checked in the browse section, so the site knows they should be referenced but aren't in the bin folder. Anyone know what's happening?

Answer (score 2):

`MySql.Data.dll` is in the GAC (Global Assembly Cache) which is why Visual Studio doesn't copy it into the bin folder *even if* `Copy Local` is true.

You could copy the assembly from the install directory (I was able to find it in `Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector xxx/Assemblies` and copy it manually to the bin folder for deployment.

Answer (score 0):

If you select your MySQL References in the solution browser, you can control if it gets copied or not to your bin folder. I forget the exact name of the propery, but it should be fairly easy to spot.

Comment: That is exactly my problem, they aren't in the development environment bin folder and therefore dont get "published" up to the host. If you try to re add them, they are already checked as if they are referenced

Comment: I just dragged and dropped the dll's to the bin folder, they are now in there. Any reason that's the wrong way to go?

Comment: Those DLLs are in the GAC, correct? Can't you just add then as a reference in your project instead of manually copying them?

Comment: And if you do have it as a reference, what's the value of the `Copy Local` property when you select it from the solution explorer?